Receive object array into flutter provider using model
I'm trying to get the data form node js backend to flutter front end.Following is newly added  attribute.How can this be receved into flutter provider using model?
sizesAndColors: [
  {
    color: { type: String },
    size: { type: String },
    quantity: { type: Number },
    images: { type: Array }
  }
]


We need enough code to reproduce the problem

Use quicktype.io to generate models.
This video will help you how to use it.
